# component group of Neron models

Tags: abelian-varieties, group-schemes, neron-models

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a discretely valued field $K$ and $\mathcal A$ its Neron model over $R$ (the ring of integers of $K$) and $\mathcal A^0$ the identity component of $\mathcal A$.

The component group $\phi= \mathcal A_k/\mathcal A_k^0$ of the special fiber is a constant group scheme over the residue field $k$.

My question: Why is $\mathcal A(R)/\mathcal A^0(R)$ isomorphic to $\phi(k)$? I know that the latter is $\mathcal A_k(k)/\mathcal A_k^0(k)$ due to Lang's theorem and I know that $\mathcal A(R)/\mathcal A^0(R)\to \mathcal A_k(k)/\mathcal A_k^0(k)$ is surjective but I can't figure out injectivity.

Comment: Note that $\mathcal A^0$ is open in $\mathcal A$ and commutes with arbitrary base change, therefore it is stable under generalizations, and if a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ lands in $\mathcal A^0_k$ under a morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec} R \to \mathcal A$, the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ must also land in $\mathcal A^0$. Therefore $f$ factors through an open subscheme $\mathcal A^0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question. If you want to make your comment into an answer I'll be glad to accept it and mark the question as answered.